# Find values created for the same description within 30 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table notifications

| id | type | date | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RC | 2020-01-01 12:14 | Login issue |
| 2 | RS | 2020-01-01 12:20 | Login issue |
| 3 | RC | 2020-02-01 13:54 | Update failed issue |
| 4 | RC | 2020-01-01 12:14 | user issue |
| 5 | RS | 2020-01-01 02:15 | user issue |

I need to find how many duplicates are created in type 'RS' for the same issue within 30 mins.

Expected Result:

| RCid | RCDate | RCdesc | RSID | RSdate | RSdesc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:14 | Login issue | 2 | 2020-01-01 12:20 | Login issue |

What I tried:

> ```
> select a.id as RCID, a.date as RCdate, a.desc as RCdesc,
> b.id as RCID, b.date as RCdate, b.desc as RCdesc from (
> select * from notifications where type = 'RC') a
> inner join 
> (select * from notifications where type = 'RC') b
> on a.desc = b.desc
> where datediff(a.date,b.date) between 0 and 30
> ```

Is there a better way?

Comment: How do you define *a duplicate for the same issue*?

Comment: Please show the results you expect.  Within 30 minutes of *what*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` as follows:

```
select t.* 
  from your_Table t
where exists 
     (select 1 from your_Table tt
       where tt.type = t.type and tt.desc = t.desc
         and abs(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.date , tt.date)) < 30
         and t.id <> tt.id)
 and t.type = 'RS';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OUTER APPLY` to select the 'within 30 minutes count' (if there is one)

```
select n.*, isnull(wc.within_30_count, 0) within_30_count
from notifications n
     outer apply (select count(*) within_30_count
                  from notifications nn
                  where n.[type] = nn.[type]
                        and abs(datediff(minute, n.[date], nn.[date]))<=30) wc;
```